# how to print array returned from watch connectivity instant message

Tags: arrays, swift, watchconnectivity

My Iphone is sending an array as a watch connectivity message. How do I print the array received on the watch? I am receiving 'nil' when I try print the array.

When I print the watch message array I'm sending, on the phone, it returns:
["message1": ["username": "Guest User", "titleItem": "Hillary ad Mirrors"]],

My code on the phone to send the message is:

func sendMessage() {

```
    var messageDataArray1 = ["username":"Guest User",  "titleItem":titleItem!]

    // Send message
    if (WCSession.defaultSession().reachable) {
        print("sending watch message array:")

        var message1 = ["message1":messageDataArray1]

        print(message1)

        WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(message1,
                                               replyHandler: { (reply) -> Void in
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                                    print("received return watch msg")
                                                })
            },
                                               errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                                    //self.receivedMessageLabel.setText("error")
                                                })
            }
        )       
    }
}
```

my code on the watch receiving controller is:

```
// MARK: - WCSessionDelegate
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    print("received Imessage from ph")
    if let msg = message["message1"] as? String {
        print(msg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message["message1"]` will give you `messageDataArray1` which is a dictionary of type `[String:String]`, but you're trying to cast it as `String` which will always fail and return `nil`.

You should cast it as `[String:String]`

```
if let userData = message["message1"] as? [String:String] {
    let username = userData["username"]
    print(username) //output: "Guest User"

    let titleItem = userData["titleItem"]
    print(titleItem)
}
```

Comment: thank you Sam_M, that works a charm. May I ask how then can I get the values in the array 'username' or 'titleItem'? I tried var unwrapTitle = message["titleItem"] as? [String:[String:String]]
        print("title is")
        print(unwrapTitle) but it returns 'nil'

Comment: @DimitriT You're welcome:) I updated the answer to show how you can get username and titleItem. I renamed `msg` to `userData` to make it more clear.